# How to use LOAD DATA INFILE statement when file is another location?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I want to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to import data in my table.

If the file is available on the same system, it works nicely and imports successfully, but when the file is located on another system, it cannot locate the path.

Can anyone explain how to use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to import data into MySQL table from another system, or remotely?

Comment: For more information, see [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html). Nevertheless, this issue is not thoroughly explained by examples. However, in accordance with this documentation (6.1.6 Security Considerations for LOAD DATA LOCAL) it is possible to transfer data in a file from a client located on a different host than the server host. Perhaps the answer @Konerak and knowledge from this link from the documentation will enable you to perform this task by trial and error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do a [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), the file must be on the system that is running the MySQL database, in the data path.

If the file is on your system, add the `LOCAL` keyword. The file will then be sent to the server, stored in a temporary directory, and run from there. This only works if the [necessary permissons are set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data-local.html).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/local/file' INTO TABLE yourtable
```

Comment: Also might need the --local-infile=1 flag when launching mysql.