# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL 5.5
Alright so here is the problem:

Using the MySQLDB module for Python, the SQL command:

```
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.csv' INTO TABLE 'example_mysql_table' TERMINATED BY ',';")
```

Doesn't work. I get `ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

I have looked around for a solution for this for a while now, and so far it seems other people having the same problem have fixed it by adding "local-infile = 1" to 'my.cnf' underneath [mysqld] and [mysql]. This has not worked for me, and I am not sure why.

Relevant Link:

[MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile)

Comment: Did you restart MySQL after modifying my.cnf? What happens when you run it with the MySQL console directly?

Comment: I did restart MySQL after modifying and it didn't change anything. The command does work when running it directly on the MySQL console, so I am assuming it is an issue with MySQLdb

Answer (score 69):

After spending hours on trying all kinds of settings in the config files and restarting mysql dozens of times I came up with this which seems to solve the problem (could not find this in any documentation anywhere)

```
MySQLdb.connect(server, username, password, database, local_infile = 1)
```

Comment: great solution, pure genius! and keeps me from editing `my.conf`

Comment: coming a little late on this thread, I was curious if this is the recommended way and also if you can pass other arguments when creating the connection similar to this.

Comment: Thanks,  this is how it should be to add the local_infile option, but not to edit my.conf.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame though that the more optimized c binding `_mysql.connect` doesn't have the same option... Any luck with that?

Answer (score 4):

As I see, there is no file option [local-infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile). But you can change this value dynamically in a script.

To view this option run this query -

```
SELECT @@global.local_infile;
```

To set variable use this statement  -

```
SET @@global.local_infile = 1;
```

---

Tested in MySQL command line console, everything is OK:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.local_infile = 1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE table1;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec)

SET @@GLOBAL.local_infile = 0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE table1;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Comment: I ran those queries in the MySQL console, and they worked, but when I added a line in my python code to set the local_infile variable to 1, ala:

cursor.execute("SELECT @@global.local_infile = 1;")

nothing changed, still got the 1148 error.

Comment: Were there any errors? Or maybe someone, or something reset this flag again? Anyway, if it works in console it should work everywhere.

Comment: Stop... You shouldn't run SELECT. Use SET statement!

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I did use the SET statement and not SELECT. It still does not work..

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem. Everything works. Have a look at answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but I thought I'd just add a little footnote regarding Flask.

I was unable to upload any csv files to MySQL via LOAD DATA INFILE, so I attempted to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. I got the same 'ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version' mentioned above.

My solution to this was to open up flaskext > mysql.py and modify the 'connect' function. I added:

```
if self.app.config['MYSQL_LOCAL_INFILE']:
    self.connect_args['local_infile'] = self.app.config['MYSQL_LOCAL_INFILE']
```

I then added:

```
app.config['MYSQL_LOCAL_INFILE'] = True
```

to my flask module. This effectively allows for the local_infile option of pymysql to be set to 'True' when using flaskext.mysql