# mysql load data infile for a list of files

Tags: python, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I am using ubuntu 12.04 operating system.  I have a folder full of `.csv` files.  I need to import all these csv files into a mysql data base on the local machine.  Currently, I have been using this syntax, from the mysql command line, to load the csv files into the data base 1 by 1:

```
load data local infile 'file_name.csv' into table table_name  fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'  lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

This works really well. I want to know if there is a way that I could load all these files at once.  My first idea was to make a python script to handle it:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
import os
import string
db=mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="XXXX",passwd="XXXX",db="test")
l = os.listdir(".")
for file_name in l:
        print file_name
        c=db.cursor()
        if (file_name.find("DIV.csv")>-1):
                c.execute("""load data local infile '%s' into table cef_div_table fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'  lines terminated by '\r\n';""" % file_name)
```

With this solution, I am running into the problem that `load data local infile` will not work with the new versions of MySQL clients, unless I start MySQL from the command line with the `--local-infile` option.  That is really a drag...

I found a solution that seemed to work.  I use the `local_file = 1` option when establishing  the connection in python (as suggested here: [MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890098/mysql-load-data-local-infile-python)).  This way, the code appears to complete without any errors, but nothing is every uploaded to the database.

It is strange, just to make sure, I tried uploading a single file from the mysql command line, and it worked file.

I am willing to try another solution to this problem of uploading multiple csv files into mysql all at once.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you may need 2 \'s before your r and n, so \\r\\n

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not make the import work.

Comment: Have you tried printing inside the if to at least make sure its getting there?

Comment: Are you insistent on using Python?

Comment: @Hoopdady - yes I have, and each file name prints out.

Comment: @ethrbunny - no, not at all

Comment: How about 'mysqlimport' and a batch file? You don't list your OS here but you should be able to spin something regardless of that.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.  I am not that great at bash scripting yet, I am on Ubuntu 12.04.  If you have an idea please feel free to leave an answer.

Comment: From what I can tell, (I use PostgreSQL and psycopg, so I might be off on this) it looks like you need to commit the transaction `db.commit()`