# MySQL load data infile using Python not working

Tags: python, mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to upload a file using MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function in Python.

In my load.py file, I have done:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, db_username, db_password, "Core_ver")
c = conn.cursor()
sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'contact.out' INTO TABLE userinfo FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (group_ID, rank_ID, login, password, first_name, last_name, email, contact_ID);"""
try:
  c.execute(sql)
  conn.commit()
except StandardError, e:
  print e
  conn.rollback()
```

Its not uploading anything. But I checked, the connection is working fine and the column names are also verified.
What might have gone wrong?

Comment: I bet this is it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13154531/771848

Comment: @alecxe
I have used `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function` several times in Python before this, but never got any issues. Moreover, it doesn't print any error to debug.

Comment: Well, also the behavior depends on [local_infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) mysql variable. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `foreign key constraint` on the table `Core_ver`. But during performing `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function` in `python`, I was not getting any errors, that's led to panic.

Anyways, the script is working fine. Thank Guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while working with mysql-connector-python. Adding the solution for that here,

```
conn = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, user=USER, 
         password=PASSWORD,port = PORT,allow_local_infile=True)
```

Only after explicitly setting  `allow_local_infile=True` the loading of csv file into the table is possible, despite the official documentation stating the value of the parameter being `True` by default. Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)