# 'Error:The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version' by mysqldb

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I try use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement by mysqldb in python.
I obtain follwing error.
OperationalError: (1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version')

and I set the  option in mysql my.cnf file :

> [mysqldump]
> quick
>
> quote-names
>
> max_allowed_packet      = 16M
>
> [mysql]
>
> no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
>
> local-infile=1
>
> [isamchk]
>
> key_buffer              = 16M

but still not working :-(

Maybe I can use some statement in MySQLdb connect function like:

> mysql --local-infile=1 -u username -p

Thanks for help
Martin

Comment: Duplicate of?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile

Comment: I try this solutions but still not working. I put local-infile=1 under [mysql] and [mysqld] headers. I try this also with local-infile. My mysql version -5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL server after modifying `my.cnf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved in 
[MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890098/mysql-load-data-local-infile-python)

```
MySQLdb.connect(server, username, password, database, local_infile = 1)
```