# load local infile not allowed perl mysql

Tags: mysql, perl

Who knows how to turn on load local infile settings in the latest MySQL on Ubuntu? I edited the  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and added

```
local-infile=1
```

And in the Perl code

```
dbConnectString=dbi:mysql:orthomcl:mysqllocalinfile=1
```

but still get

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version...
```

It is used by an application called OrthoMCL

I tried configuring `my.cnf` file:

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
local-infile = 1
[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
local-infile = 1
```

Then a restart of the mysql server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 9563
```

But then I still get:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version at ../Apps/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.3/bin/orthomclLoadBlast line 39, <F> line 12.
The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version at ../Apps/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.3/bin/orthomclLoadBlast line 39, <F> line 12.`
```

Line 39 is:

```
$stmt->execute() or die DBI::errstr;
```

which executes the lines above:

```
my $sql = "
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE \"$blastFile\"
REPLACE INTO TABLE $sst
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'
";
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: [Set Load Infile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile) Update the facing issues  @Jasper

Comment: I updated my post above, and mentioned that I indeed tried that post in several ways but none seems to work.

Comment: your `dbConnectString` has a weird format for me. It should be like `dbi:DriverName:database_name`

Comment: Changed it to dbConnectString=dbi:mysql:orthomcl but no success.

Comment: Please make attempt using the `mysqlimport` command

Answer (score 7):

```
dbConnectString=dbi:mysql:orthomcl:mysql_local_infile=1:localhost:3306
```

I added also in mysql.cnf
under

```
[client]
      loose-local-infile=1
```

worked for me

Comment: Adding mysql_local_infile=1 to the DBI DSN should be sufficient.