# #1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

04,
Am trying to load a csv file into a database but its giving the error

```
#1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

my Code to load file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//home//triveni//Documents//test.csv'
INTO TABLE 1981_5
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(question,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,answer6,rightAnswer,Marks)
```

and the data in the file is

```
Whartsdf,dsfds,sdfdsf,sdfdsf,sdfds,sdf,fsdf,2,2
```

Any One Please help me i have tried all the possibilities changed the privileges, Tried of only`LOAD DATA INFILE`
But I dint got the solution...

And its working good in Windows OS
Is This OS Problem????

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile

Comment: gowri is right, the provided solution is the correct one. For me, just adding local_infile=on in the [mysql] section solved the problem.