# Load data local infile does not work in Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Using MySQL I cannot import a file using load data local infile. My server is on AWS RDS. This works on Ubuntu 10.04. I installed the client using `apt-get install mysql-client`. Same error if I use mysqldb or mysql.connector in Python.

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 479, in cmd_query
    return self.handle_cmd_result(self.conn.recv())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 179, in recv_plain
    errors.raise_error(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/errors.py", line 82, in raise_error
    raise get_mysql_exception(errno,errmsg)
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I have a lot of data to upload... I can't believe 12.04 is not supported and I have to use 12.04.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a python question... but the long and short of the matter is that mysql, as compiled and distributed by Ubuntu > 12.04, does not support using `load data local infile` directly from the mysql client as is.

If you search the MySQL Reference Documentation for Error 1148, further down the page linked above, in the comments:

> Posted by Aaron Peterson on November 9 2005 4:35pm
>
> With a defalut installation from FreeBSD ports, I had to use the command line
>   mysql -u user -p --local-infile menagerie
>   to start the mysql monitor, else the LOAD DATA LOCAL command failed with an error like 
>   the following:
>
> ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

... which *does* work.

```
monte@oobun2:~$ mysql -h localhost -u monte -p monte --local-infile
Enter password: 

...

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 8  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM pet;
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name     | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Fluffy   | Harold | cat     | f    | 1993-02-04 | NULL       |
| Claws    | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Buffy    | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
| Fang     | Benny  | dog     | m    | 1990-08-27 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane  | dog     | m    | 1979-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Chirpy   | Gwen   | bird    | f    | 1998-09-11 | NULL       |
| Whistler | Gwen   | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
| Slim     | Benny  | snake   | m    | 1996-04-29 | NULL       |
| Puffball | Diane  | hamster | f    | 1999-03-30 | NULL       |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I generally don't need to load data via code, so that suffices for my needs.  If you do, and have the ability/permissions to edit your mysql config file, then the `local-infile=1` line in the appropriate section(s) may be simpler.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to go with command line.  I made the change to the config...no go.  Python api's will just not work.