# using mysql LOAD statment in PHP fails, but doing it via command line works

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php web page that let's a person upload a file.
I want to extract the file name from $_FILE and then load all the data into my database.

My code looks like this:

```
 $myfile = $_FILE['file']['tmp_file'];
 $executebatchloadsql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'. $myfile .'" INTO TABLE testtable (fname, lname);
 mysql_query($executebatchloadsql) or die(mysql_error());
```

But the error message I'm getting says:

> The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

My questions are as follows

1. Am I supposed to use the `tmp_file` name or the name?
2. What do I need to do to get the load data command to work? I've tried to follow the post found at [MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile) but it's still giving me the same error.

**EDIT 1:**

This is what my /etc/mysql/my.cnf looks like in part:

```
[mysqld]

user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
local-infile
```

The last line is what I added.  I also added the same line to the [mysql] section:

```
[mysql]
local-infile
```

After making these changes, I restarted sql:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

But I'm still having the problem

**EDIT 2:**

I've also tried local-infile=1 as per the same post I mention above.
But that doesn't work either.

**EDIT 3**

I've tried to add the FILE prvil to the user.. like so:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO root;
```

and then when i showit grants for root, i can see that its been added.  but i'm still getting an error message that the used command is not allowed on my version of mysql.
Do I need the "=1" after the infile in my my.cfg file?

**EDIT 4:**

As a further test, i tried loading the file manually via command line instead of via php and it accepted it.  I logged in as root (which is the same id i'm using my app for testing purposes) and then I tried the following command:

```
mysql> load data local infile '/var/www/testwebsite/abc.csv' into table testtable;
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 48 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 48
```

But I can't seem to get the PHP code working.
Thanks.!

Comment: what version of mysql are you using, and are you using mysql_, mysqli_ or pdo?

Comment: Does your server allow `LOAD DATA` and is it configured to do so?

Comment: Make sure your MySQL user has the `FILE` privilege granted. There's also a chance your hosting provider has blocked you doing this command if you're using shared hosting.

Comment: Please see my updated comments next to question 2.  also, mysql version is 5.5.28.  Also, I'm using mysql_connect() which I guess means I'm not using mysqli or pdo...

Comment: sorry, i tried formatting the ini file data properly... but for some reason, it keeps turning out really difficult to read!

Comment: As Jamie suggested exec command `SHOW GRANTS FOR username;` and see if the user has `GRANT FILE ON *.*` OR `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*` with `mysql` or whatever IDE you use (phpAdmin, Sequel Pro...)

Comment: @jamie can u expand on the file privilege comment a little further?  I will googlehow to do that

Comment: @peterm I will give that a try when I get back to the office.  Thankyou for clarification

Comment: `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO username` will give the necessary right for the user username.

Answer (score 2):

After going from MySQL 5.0 to 5.5 I found out that I suddenly have to enable LOCAL INFILE specifically when creating the connection in PHP.

Using mysql:

```
mysql_connect(server,user,code,false,128); // 128 enables LOCAL INFILE
mysql_select_db(database);
```

Using mysqli:

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($conn,server,user,code,database);
```