# Enabling local-infile for loading data into remote mysql from rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, activerecord

Im using connection_ninja (https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja) to connect to a remote mysql database from my rails applicaion. I have a method in my model which loads a csv file using 'load data local infile..' from the server running my rails app into the remote mysql db.

The code is as follows :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  @conn = use_connection_ninja(:rl_op)
  self.table_name = 'RlProduct'

  def self.update(file_path)
    sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '#{file_path}'
           INTO TABLE RlProduct
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
           (name,price,productId)"               

    @conn.connection().execute(sql)
  end      
end
```

This is giving me the following error :

```
Mysql2::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE..
```

I have set `local-infile=1` in `[mysql]` section of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` of the server running my rails app. And that allows me to import the data into remote db if i directly log in to mysql on the server and run the load data local.. command there.

How can i set local-infile=1 for my rails code as well ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

add this to `database.yml`:

```
local_infile: true
```

Comment: I love you! Been looking everywhere for this

Comment: yeah, that's not the most often used feature ) enjoy ;)

Comment: where i can find this file... i am using mysql server 5.6

Comment: it's in the `config` directory of your Rails project, you should add the line to your environment config (ie. development)

Comment: One of the most under-rated answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The user that is running this query should have `FILE` access on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It works on my dev machine. I just have a problem on the server where the app is deployed. I need to enable local-infile for mysql client on the server.I have enabled it by making the entry in my.cnf as sated above.However,rails is not aware of that setting. So how can i enable it for my rails code as well ?

Comment: you are right. the difference is local vs remote. The same user behaves differently when accessed via localhost or remote. Check the host value for this user. It should be `%` instead of localhost.