# PHP csv file upload in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, permissions

I am trying to upload a csv file into my mysql database from php code.
I am getting an error: ***"Could not updated:The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"***

This is the code I am using.
Do i have to give any kinds of permissions so that I am able to do it from php forms.?
As I am able to load this same csv file from mysql directly from terminal.

P.S.:- I have changed my.cnf file after reading this post.
[MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile)

How ever i am unable to upload from phpmyadmin and from php forms. Error Message is same. i.e. ***"Could not updated:The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"***

Below is the piece of code.

```
if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $name = $file['name'];
    $type = $file['type'];
    $size = $file['size'];
    $tmppath = $file['tmp_name']; 
    echo "Name of the file is $name <br> $tmppath";
    if($name!="")
    {
        echo "<br> Trying to upload file <br>";         
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmppath, "csvfiles/.$name")) //project is a folder in which you will save csv files
        {
            $query="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tmppath' INTO TABLE test.metadata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;";
            mysql_query ($query) or die ('Could not updated:'.mysql_error());
            echo "CSV file inserted successfully !!<br>";
        }else {echo "<br>Failed !!!!";}
    }else {echo "<br>No file exist <br>";}
}else {echo " <br> No file exist <br>";}
```

Comment: The version of MySQL you are using seems an appropriate thing to include.

Comment: Its MySql 5.5, latest one I could get from apt-get install command.

Answer (score 0):

If `LOAD DATA LOCAL` is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:

```
ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Try to run below in if UNIX

```
mysql_fix_privilege_tables --password=root_password
```

or if windows

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0"
C:\> bin\mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql> SOURCE share/mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.4 and when I run mysql_fix_privilege_tables --password=root_password it gives me error command not found.

Comment: Can you run `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: I got this error.

Could not create the upgrade info file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MySQL Servers datadir, errno: 13

Comment: I did it using superuser, It is upgraded now.

Comment: Nope, the upgrade did not work, I guess coz I am getting the same error when i try to load the file from php form.

Comment: Well I have solved the issue guys/girls, used fgetcsv() instead of LOAD LOCAL DATA... Thanks to everyone....