# Error 1148. Editing /etc/mysql/my.cnf File

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   '/home/local/ANT/gwwallen/Downloads/oak3_template_finder.csv' INTO
>   TABLE test.oak3_template_finder FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY
>   '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

MySQL Workbench

into my MySQL DB Table. But I am getting the **Error 1148**, I have read I need to modify my.cnf file to say local-infile = 1 under [mysql] and [mysqld]. I can locate the file, and make the changes, but the Save button is greyed out. I am fairly new to linux so I am not sure if I need to chmod the file or what. I have done this LOAD DATA on my local windows machine at home, but cannot do it on my Linux. I really need this to work, I'm not sure what this issue is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile)

Comment: That does presenta solution of what to change, but I have added local-infile=1 under [mysql] and [mysqld]. But, when I go into MySQL Workbench to run the script it still gives me the 1148 error. Would I need to restart MYSQL after updating my.cnf, is there another file to also edit. If restart, how? Not too familiar with linux.

Comment: yes, you need to restart the server