# Loading csv file into MYSQL table using LOAD INFILE

Tags: mysql, database, file, load, load-data-infile

I am trying to load a small file into a dummy table created on MYSQL but I get these below errors when I try running the commands.Please kindly help me regarding this. Thank you.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/ravitejavutukuri/Desktop/Acme Reports/abc.txt' INTO TABLE dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/ravitejavutukuri/Desktop/Acme Reports/abc.txt' INTO TABLE dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/ravitejavutukuri/Desktop/Acme Reports/abc.txt' INTO TABLE dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql> local-infile=1
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'local-infile=1' at line 1
```

Comment: Your screen shot is too small to read. Post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential problems.

1. You need to create the table `user`
2. You need to set the option `local-infile=1` in MySQL ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile))
3. You may need to allow permissions for that user. If you want to do this quickly, you can use: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';`

Comment: local-infile=1
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'local-infile=1' at line 1

Comment: local-infile is a parameter you can pass when you launch MySQL, or you can permanently add it to your my.cnf file.