# Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, r, ubuntu, file-io, import

R programming language

This is my query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ap_506/KF/export_2015-07-20.csv'
INTO TABLE test.raporty
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I put `local-infile=1` in file: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` :

```
[mysql]
local-infile=1
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
```

and it still returns error:

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Version:

`SELECT VERSION()` returns: `'5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1'`

It works and I can upload this via terminal using:

```
mysql -h <server> -u <user> -p --local-infile <database>
```

and I can upload this from WINDOWS too

but that's not a soultion, beacause I need to use ubuntu and upload data from R. Can you help me?

Comment: I read all tutorials on stackoverflow but I didn't find solution...

Comment: look of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile

Answer (score 0):

I found partial solution. I added in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` 2 lines:

```
[odbc]
local-infile=1
```

and I can use query `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` through RODBC in R, but there is still same problem with Workbench: `Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.` Any ideas? How can I check what drivers Workbench is using?