# Seed Rails database (MySQL) from TSV file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, macos, rake

While developing my Rails app, I've been manually seeding its database with sample data. However, after I run `rake db:migrate:reset` I need to re-seed everything, which is tedious.

**How can I get `rake` to seed the database for me?**

The relevant model is generated in this migration:

```
class CreateKeyRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :key_records, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :parentID, :limit => 8
      t.primary_key :ID
      t.integer :accesses, :limit => 8
      t.integer :dt
      t.integer :hour
    end
    change_column :key_records, :ID, 'bigint'
  end
end
```

Currently, I'm seeding the db by directly altering the app's database in `mysql`, with the command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/input.tsv' INTO TABLE key_records (name, parentID, ID, accesses) SET dt=20141231, hour=23;
```

where `input.tsv` has the form:

```
key   1    2    9493878
```

How might I get rake to do this 'manual seeding' for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a "rails-ey" way of doing this, but you should be able to run a SQL statement in `seeds.rb`.  You can run raw SQL statements against your database with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.  Your seed file would look something like this:

```
stmt = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/input.tsv' 
    INTO TABLE key_records (name, parentID, ID, accesses) 
    SET dt=20141231, hour=23;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute stmt
```

You would then call it with `rake db:seed`.

Comment: It didn't work :( I think the issue is that by default `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is disabled, but I don't know how to enable it in rails (I enabled it in regular mysql with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile)). Do you know how I might enable it in Rails?

Comment: Add `local_infile: true` to your database.yml and see if that works - also, make sure the user your app is using has appropriate permissions.