# The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version within R Studio

Tags: r, azure, rmysql

I have a MYSQL (which I'm very new to) database hosted on azure, which i'm trying to write data to from RStudio using the `RMySQL` package.

I am receiving the following message

```
> dbWriteTable(searchdb,"searchrecords",data, append = TRUE)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
 could not run statement: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Can anybody provide a suggestion as to why this may be?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but being completely new to MySQL, I wouldn't have the first clue of how to follow these instructions.

Comment: i had the same problem, but i cant remember how i solved it. will research and post when i find it

Comment: answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile