# Web2py: pass parameters to db Connection()

Tags: mysql, web2py

In web2py, in gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py there is a function that creates a new mySQL connection:

```
def __init__(self, host="localhost", user=None, passwd="",
             db=None, port=3306, unix_socket=None,
```

Is there any way to pass parameters to this function from web2py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted at the very end of [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Note-on-new-DAL-and-adapters) of the documentation, you can specify a dictionary of `driver_args` when instantiating `DAL`:

```
db = DAL(<connection_string>,
         driver_args=dict(host='localhost', port=3306, ...))
```

Comment: Perfect. Sorry that I missed that.