# PDO failing with MySQL and LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement from MySQL and I am getting the error that "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version".

The data file is local to the server running MySql.  **I can run the same command from MySql Workbench (installed on the same machine) and it works fine.**  This suggests to me that the server is setup to accept the command, and that the problem is probably with my PHP PDO client (again, on the same machine).

Here's the code where I create the PDO:

```
function getDb() {
    $dsn        = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db';
    $username   = 'username';
    $password   = 'password';
    $options    = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true];
    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

As you can see, I am setting the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` when I create the object.

Here's the sql command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/media/working/my_file.psv' 
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile

Answer (score 0):

> I can run the same command from MySql Workbench (installed on the
>   same machine) and it works fine.

- Are you sure there is only one mysql version on server?
- Are you sure
  that script and you from console are using the same db user with same
  rights?

Comment: Yes and Yes - only one mysqld process is running, and I have only one user (root)