# error in using a shell script ".sh" to load data into the database using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

In order to load my assignment's data, I followed these directions

> Run "mysql < createdb.sql" to create database schema. Run
>   "./loaddata.sh" to load data into the database.

I have successfully ran the createdb.sql using this command line

> mysql> source /user/Desktop/sqllab/createdb.sql;

So what I have now is database but with empty tables.

To load the data from "loaddata.sh", I tried the command line

> mysql> source /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh;

but I got this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'for f in student faculty class enrolled emp dept
>   works flights aircraft employee' at line 1

this is what's inside the loaddata.sh file

```css
#! /bin/sh
# Load data in plain text files to tables


for f in student faculty class enrolled emp dept works flights aircraft employees certified suppliers parts catalog 
do
 echo "Inserting $f"
 mysql --local-infile lab -e "load data local infile '$f.txt' into table $f columns terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\r\n'"
done
```

when I run

> /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh

I get:

> Inserting student /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8:
>   mysql: command not found 
>   Inserting faculty
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting class /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8:
>   mysql: command not found Inserting enrolled
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting emp /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8:
>   mysql: command not found Inserting dept
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting works /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8:
>   mysql: command not found Inserting flights
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting aircraft /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line
>   8: mysql: command not found Inserting employees
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting certified /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh:
>   line 8: mysql: command not found Inserting suppliers
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found Inserting parts /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8:
>   mysql: command not found Inserting catalog
>   /user/Desktop/sqllab/loaddata.sh: line 8: mysql: command not
>   found

Comment: that is being treated as if it is a .sql file with valid mysql commands. Which it is not one. No? It accepts and ignores the comment lines (#), and blows up on the `for f`

Comment: doc page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) as you know. So when it says a sql batch file, it does not mean a bash batch file :p

Comment: ?? Did you try running `/path/to/loaddata.sh` **from a unix/linux shell command line**, per your instructions? That should work fine. If not, edit your Q to include a reasonable sample of error messages. Good luck.

Comment: I'm not a mysql user, so I looked here for `[mysql] load data local infile` and found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile . Did this code work for any of your class mates, or is your instructor the sort that deliberately gives you code that requires some research to fix? Good luck.