# empty set after load data in file mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using pymysql to load a large csv file into a database, because of memory limitations im using load infile rather than insert. however after the code completes when i query the server it for the data in the table it returns an empty set.

```
import pymysql


conn = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost', port = 3306, user = 'root', passwd = '', local_infile = True)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test`DEFAULT "
            "CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            "`test`.`scores` ( `date` DATE NOT NULL, "
            "`name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,"
            "`score` DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL);")
conn.commit()

def push(fileName = '/home/pi/test.csv', tableName = '`test`.`scores`'):
    push = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "%s" INTO TABLE %s
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
           IGNORE 1 LINES
           (date, name, score);""" % (fileName, tableName)
    cur.execute(push)
    conn.commit()
push()
```

I get some truncation warnings but no other errors or warnings to work off of. any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a few things to fix this, First I changed the config files for my sql server to allow load infile, following this [MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile). Then the problem was with the line,

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

the fix was to change it to

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

after that the script runs fine and is significantly faster than inserting row by row