# How to fix bulk loading with MySQL python connector

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, bulk-load

I am trying to bulk load multiple csv files into a MySQL database that has already been set up. My main issue is with the actual execution of the loading because it looks like everything else is set up properly

I have tried looking around on stack to possibly find a solution to this problem, but since I am new to MySQL and python I have had very little luck

```
delimiter=r','

dateString=r'%d-%b-%Y'
file=fileName.split("/")[-1]

c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmStaging fields terminated by %s ignore 1 lines(symbol,series,open,high,low,close,last,prevclose,tottrdqty,tottrdval,@timestamp,totaltrades,isin) SET timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@timestamp, %s)",(fileName,delimiter,dateString))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled4/loadCMfiles.py", line 59, in 
    insertRows(localExtractFilePath+"/"+file,c)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled4/loadCMfiles.py", line 48, in insertRows
    c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmStaging fields terminated by %s ignore 1 lines(symbol,series,open,high,low,close,last,prevclose,tottrdqty,tottrdval,@timestamp,totaltrades,isin) SET timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@timestamp, %s)",(fileName,delimiter,dateString))
  File "/Users/admin/.conda/envs/W/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/Users/admin/.conda/envs/W/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 395, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the exact LoonyCorn assignment you're doing :)

Make sure you're passing allow_local_infile=True to the mysql.connector.connect(**config) statement like so:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'user': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': '127.XXXX',
    'database': 'nse',
    'use_pure': True,
    'allow_local_infile': True
}

conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

Just a heads up: you may need to additionally follow the steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XM2xx-PD4cg&vl=en) if this doesn't work--I tried the steps in the video, including updating `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile#answer-11538902) and none of them worked; however they may still be necessary with the above solution.

Good luck!