# Travis build fails with error LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql, travis-ci

UPD: The question is different from [MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile)

That question is related to LOCAL run and nothing to do with travis build, locally, using that options everything works like a charm, no problem with it, but running in travis, also requesting mysql not with mysql client, but programmaticaly -  so i can't set any client option, this  makes my case different.

i am trying to set up travis build - and running into error

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2068, 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.')
```

I tried local_infile option, as i do on my local system:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -e 'SET GLOBAL local_infile=1'
```

(I tried this option at before install section, at install section)

But still it doesn't help.

I am completly stuck without ideas where to move further. Appreciate any help.

My travis config is following:

```
 language: python
os: linux
dist: jammy

services:
  - mysql

python:
  - "3.10.5"

env:
  - TESTENV=test

before_install:
  - mysql -u root -h localhost -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "travis"@"%"'
install:
  - pip3 install --upgrade pip
  - pip3 install --upgrade setuptools wheel
  - mysql -u root -h localhost -e 'SET GLOBAL local_infile=1'
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  - if [[ "$TESTENV" != "docs" ]]; then pip3 install -r requirements-test.txt; fi
  - pip3 install -e .

script:
  - if [[ "$TESTENV" == "test" ]]; then coverage run -m pytest --server=mysql://travis@127.0.0.1:3306/ src/tests; fi
  - if [[ "$TESTENV" == "test" ]]; then coverage report -m; fi
```

Comment: You need to set `local-infile` both in the server (which you did with the SET GLOBAL command) and also in the client, with `mysql --local-infile ...`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html for documentation and examples.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't have client, it is my application that works with mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL DSN might accept `local_infile=1` as an argument. Example:

```
coverage run -m pytest --server=mysql://travis@127.0.0.1:3306/?local_infile=1 src/tests
```

I can't confirm this, because the versions of `coverage` and `pytest` I have installed don't recognize the `--server` option. I can't find any documentation of that flag. So I don't know exactly what you're using.

Also the support for the `local_infile` option may depend on which database driver you're using, e.g. mysql.connector, pymysql, etc.