# how to import data to the mysql database from a text file located in the server

Tags: php, mysql, file, codeigniter, load-data-infile

i am successful to import data from my local pc but the problem is,it is not working on the server
here is the code that works fine when i load the file from pc directory

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test.txt' INTO TABLE pet fields terminated by ',';
```

but it doesn't work when i put server location like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'http://localhost/farzana/erp_fiat/files/test.text' INTO TABLE pet fields terminated by ',';
```

it will be very helpful if someone fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `test.text` with `test.txt` in the url and paste the URL in the browser if you can see the file,

else use the absolute path of the directory, instead of the URL

Comment: how will i use absolute path when i upload it to the remote server..?

Comment: check the output of `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`, try usign this , it should be your path to the application, then you can add your file location from there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove LOCAL if you are loading it from server.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'http://localhost/farzana/erp_fiat/files/test.txt' INTO TABLE pet fields terminated by ',';
```

Comment: Did u try changing test.text to test.txt ???

Comment: Try opening this link http://localhost/farzana/erp_fiat/files/test.txt in browser if text file opens/downloads..It must work else something problem with   the link ...Try once ?

Comment: yes i tried it shows the data of the text file..

Comment: Try adding port number in the path given .. May be 8080???

Comment: http://localhost:8080/farzana/erp_fiat/files/test.txt

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965141/2173793):

> When you do a LOAD DATA INFILE, the file must be on the system that is running the MySQL database, in the data path.
>
> If the file is on your system, add the LOCAL keyword.

Try to remove the `LOCAL` key word.

Comment: i tried this too but not working

Comment: Is your file path correct?