# where to save file when trying to load into database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm doing some work with databases, and I want to play around with the ability to load file content into a table. Currently I'm using a host server for a website, and using phpmyadmin to interact with MySQL. My questions is where do you save the file you want to load if you aren't using a local host? Everything I've read deals with local hosting, but what if I have a file that I have saved on an external server? I thought maybe something like `LOAD DATA INFILE 'url to file' INTO TABLE [table name]` would work, but instead I get an error.

Do I need to save this locally on my computer and then have it somehow read the file from a local path? I'm not sure this is normally done.

Comment: mysql can't handle urls. it's not a web client, it will not reach "outside" the server to download something. `load data` will accept a filesystem path only: a local path on the machine running the mysql client, or a server-side path when not using `load local`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LOAD DATA INFILE statement when file is another location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965043/how-to-use-load-data-infile-statement-when-file-is-another-location)

Comment: Are you trying to do this through phpMyAdmin or with your own LOAD DATA INFILE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

If you have SSH access to the MySQL Server Machine, do a SSH login to the machine and

- Start the mysql client with `--local-infile=1`

  `mysql --local-infile=1 -u username -p yourdb`
- Load the file (assuming it is in your current directory) to the table

  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'namelist.csv' INTO TABLE customers COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',';`

### Option 2

If you don't have SSH access to the remote database server

- Create a database instance in your local machine MySQL server
- Load Data as shown in option #1
- use `mysqldump -u username -p yourdb importedtbl > tbldump.sql`
- If your remote Webserver has phpMyAdmin to connect to your remote database server, use it import the table dump to your remote server.